# Why won't the JFrame display the output?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I've declared the JFrame in the applet. The JFrame seems to open (I can see only the open, close and maximize buttons) but shows no output.

```
 public class LaunchListener implements ActionListener
 {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
     {

          String input;
          int coInput;

          input = integerInput.getText();
          coInput = Integer.parseInt(input);

          JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
          JFrame frame=new JFrame("Add JTextArea into JFrame");

        if (convInput == 2)
        {
            String output = "Show output";

            frame.add(textArea);
            textArea.setText(output);
            frame.setVisible(true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you forget the method

```
setBounds(x,y,width,height);
```

actually `setBounds` can be dividen in 2 methods

```
setSize(w,h);

setLocation(x,y);
```

Comment: Wow, so that was what was wrong with it. Thank you, your simple explanation helped me fix it.

Comment: `pack` and possibly `setLocationByPlatform` might be better choices